# Exception "Invalid cell coordinate V"

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to read an Excel2007 template, edit it and save it to a new Excel2007 file.

The template is made of 7 worksheets, with 50 cols and 2000 rows per worksheet, and it weights 2.6Mb empty.

When I attempt to save the file, even if I do nothing with the template, I'v always got this exception :

```
Invalid cell coordinate V
```

I understand that somewhere in the template, a formulae is looking to a cell with its column, but no row is specified. I can't found any formulae like this.

I'v noticed if I specify

```
$PHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
```

before saving, the exception is not thrown, but saved file is corrupted.

--- EDIT ---

I forgot to mention that my template have many combo box. Is that what could cause this error ?

Comment: Upload the culprit template workbook to the codeplex problems so the problem can be properly investigated.... the PHPExcel forums should be the first port of call for any problems with the library. The problem may not relate to a formula, but any defined name or range.